# Magento 2: Not showing customers in backend grid

Tags: php, magento2

We have a site that has approximately 300.000 customers.
Sometimes the customers won't show up on the admin panel. For that we do 
    php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
This process was already made http://prntscr.com/f71rro .

We have tried several things that might solve this issue:
        - Change the status directly on the data base and reindex again 
        - update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';
        - php bin/magento indexer:reindex

- Increase the `limit_memory`  on  php.ini
- Change PHP version to 5.6

Could you please help us and see what other solutions we could apply for this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is due to indexing issue. You can check customer index status in admin. Run below commands to fix customer index issue

```
    1) php bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid

    2) php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```